# How to package web-inf/* and meta-inf/* to a war file via zip command?

Tags: zip

I have a foo.war file (JSF web app). I unzipped it just fine.

```
unzip foo.war
```

Then meta-inf and web-inf folders are extracted. I made a change to a properties file inside of web-inf and I repackageed it as foo.war.

However below command I tried didn't do it. It left out package name and Java classes under it from classes folder.

```
zip foo.war META-INF/* WEB-INF/*
```

Comment: zip -r foo.war META-INF/ WEB-INF/ worked

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please consider closing your question (or answering it, though I have a feeling "recursive zipping" has already been brought here). ;)

Answer (score 2):

running follow command fixed the problem.

```
zip -r foo.war META-INF/ WEB-INF/
```

Comment: the more general solution `zip -r foo.war *` should work too